# Animation with merged objects issue

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, weight-painting, parent

I made a human character mesh and then merged two other meshes: his glasses and his hair, like in this image.
[image: Human character]

Then I made a simple rig for it, and I parented the mesh to the rig. When it came to weight painting, this is how I painted the vertex group corresponding to the neck.

[image]
[image]

Now I want the head to be able to rotate around the X (red) axis. The issue is, the hair and glasses seem to rotate at a different ratio (faster than the head), angle-wise.

[image]
[image]

I have no idea why this happens, since the glasses as well as the hair are joined into the character's mesh. I couldn't go with the automatically generated weights because they were messed up.

I'm a newbie to Blender so I expect I do something wrong. I'd highly appreciate any tip regarding this issue.

[image]

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will remember to do this at my eventual next questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the hair and glass parts in *Edit* mode, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, and on the right of the list, click on the down arrow and choose *Remove from All Groups*, then select the group you want these vertices to be part of (for example *Head* if the head bone is called *Head*) and click on the *Assign* button under the vertex groups list

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't this exact issue but it lead me straight to the solution. I looked at all the vertices in character's head composition and the problem was they were assigned to many other bones of the body (automatically). I removed these vertices from all these other vertex groups (besides the head group and neck group). Now everything's working fine!